# RegEx expression to select folder path of a file type

Tags: regex

I am looking to make a Regex expression to find places where pdf files are referenced, and select their folder path.

For example for the expression `"http://folders/../file.pdf"` it should select
`"http://folders/../`

The issue is that I only want it to select pdf files and escape if it hits a second quotation mark (`"http://folders/other"` doesn't have anything get selected)

I currently have two regex expressions that each do half of what I want:

`"(.[^"]*?)(?=\.pdf")` selects all the paths that end with a pdf, but includes the filename.

`"(.[^"]*[\/])` properly grabs just the folder path, but does it for all links.

Is there a way I can get a regex expression that selects just the folder path only when the file ends with a .pdf extension?

Comment: which tool are you using?

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A positive lookahead `(?= )` would be usefull

```
"(.[^"]*[\/])(?=.*\.pdf"$)
```

see the example

http://regex101.com/r/gT6kI4/1

**Explanation**

`"(.[^"]*[\/])` matches the path

`(?=.*\.pdf"$)` asserts that the path is followed by something (`.*`) and ends with `.pdf`